# What is the meaning of "tag up"?

Tags: american-english, terminology, north-american-english

I am not a native speaker, in a business environment, I saw my American colleagues use this term often in MS-Outlook (setting up meetings) and e-mails. For example, it might appear in a meeting notice's subject line:

> Tag up on Project-X

Is this equivalent to "catch up on something"?

What troubles me is that I can't even find this term anywhere in online dictionaries. And this looks so popular that I feel shame/shy to ask. Could anybody share with me some links from where I can catch up on these popular  jargon? Thank you

Comment: It means more like let’s get together to get or make sure we stay aligned on something.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could tell us more of the context.  If you google "tag up" you'll get information re: baseball terminology that may explain how your colleagues are using it.

Comment: @Daniel: Does my answer make sense to you in terms of how you've seen this used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"tag up" is a baseball metaphor.  Tagging up is "touching base," as in "let's touch base on our overseas marketing strategy before our trip to Europe."

Converted to a noun, a "tag up" is a meeting to touch base about something to ensure that everyone's starting from the same place--that is, has the same understanding of the approach being taken.

From Wikipedia: [Tag up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_up)

> In baseball, to tag up is for a baserunner to retouch or remain on
>   their starting base (the time-of-pitch base) until (after) the ball
>   either lands in fair territory or is first touched by a fielder. By
>   rule, baserunners must tag up when a fly ball is caught in flight by a
>   fielder.